# Proper selector for selecting parent items only in an unordered list

Tags: jquery-selectors, css

I have an unordered list as follows:

```
<ul id="menu">
    <li><a href="#">Event Overview</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li><a href="#">About</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Blog</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

    <li><a href="#">Contact</a>
        <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Some Text Here</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>

</ul>
```

I need to select all of the parent list items, but not the children list items. For instance, I need to select The list items that contains "event overview" but not the list items that contain "some text here".

Typically, my selector would be as follows `#menu-nav li` but this selects all list items, including children.

What is the proper selector for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Child Selector (cue angels singing):

```
#menu > li
```

It will only select the `li` elements that are *direct* children of `#menu`.

Comment: No, it won't. As well as `$('#menu').children()` won't :)

Comment: @Dampe, yes it does: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bqYRw/1/). The other descendant `li` elements inherited the background assigned to the `#menu > li` elements (since they're the descendants of those elements). I updated your demo to assign a different, `#fff`, `background-color` to the second-level `li` elements.

Comment: @sdleihssirhc: Uf..what a silly mistake. Sorry, you are correct.

Comment: @Dampe, no problem at all; my apologies if it felt like criticism. That wasn't my intent (trust me, I have, and probably everyone else has also, made sillier mistakes...) =)

Comment: @David Thomas: Np, I know I might not be always right. It's good when someone corrects me AND shows me why ;)